# My code is running without any errors, but word document is not correct

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I run my code in debug mode and it runs perfectly, but the word document is showing some entries ok, and others with multiples of the same data, and others with the error of nothing there, even on columns not addressed.
Here is the what my code looks like:

```vb
    Sub sWordTables(daSN2, daGL, daST, daSY, daBEY, daENY, daSUP)

     Dim daDB As DAO.Database
     Dim appWord As Object 'Word.Application
     Dim WordDoc As Object 'Word.Document
     Dim wdTable As Object 'Word.Table'
     Dim cname As String
     Dim cnum As String
     Dim gss As Integer
     Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
     Dim aVar As String
     Dim tableIndex As Integer
 
 
     Dim strPath As String
     Dim IntHolder As Integer
     Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 
     strPath = "C:\Users\wpulk\Documents\"
 
    Set daDB = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = daDB.OpenRecordset("qry" & daST, dbOpenDynaset)
      Set WordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(strPath & "MasterRecord2.docx")
     tableIndex = 1
     Do While Not rst.EOF
 
            cname = rst!CourseName
            cnum = rst!CourseNumber
            gss = rst!GradeScore
            incn = rst!IncrementNumber
        
        With WordDoc
     
            If tableIndex = 1 Then
                .Variables.Add ("StudentName"), daSN2
                .Variables.Add ("Supervisor"), daSUP
                .Variables.Add ("SchoolYear"), daSY
                .Variables.Add ("GradeLevel"), daGL
                .Variables.Add ("BeginDate"), daBEY
                .Variables.Add ("EndDate"), daENY
            
            End If
            If tableIndex >= 2 Then
    Select Case cname
        Case "Math"
            .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "a"), cnum
            .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "b"), gss
        Case "English"
            .Variables.Add ("Eng" & incn & "a"), cnum
            .Variables.Add ("Eng" & incn & "b"), gss
        Case "Word Building"
            .Variables.Add ("WB" & incn & "a"), cnum
            .Variables.Add ("WB" & incn & "b"), gss
         Case "Literature"
            .Variables.Add ("Lit" & incn & "a"), cnum
            .Variables.Add ("Lit" & incn & "b"), gss
        Case "Science"
            .Variables.Add ("Science" & incn & "a"), cnum
            .Variables.Add ("Science" & incn & "b"), gss
         Case "Social Studies"
            .Variables.Add ("SocS" & incn & "a"), cnum
            .Variables.Add ("SocS" & incn & "b"), gss
         Case "Bible"
           .Variables.Add ("Bible" & incn & "a"), cnum
           .Variables.Add ("Bible" & incn & "b"), gss
         Case "Florida History"
             .Variables.Add ("oth" & incn & "a"), cnum
             .Variables.Add ("oth" & incn & "b"), gss
   End Select
        End If
        End With
        If tableIndex > 1 Then
         rst.MoveNext
        End If
        tableIndex = tableIndex + 1
    
    Loop
        appWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
        appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strPath & "MasterRecord" & daST & ".docx"
          Set WordDoc = Nothing
          Set appWord = Nothing

    End Sub
```

I expected the code would write  into the word document correctly, and it does not.

Comment: All your variable are linked to content controls?

Comment: All my variables are desginated as document variables with field names

Comment: Would be helpful to have raw data and Word document. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files.

Comment: Why are the ActiveDocument Update and SaveAs actions not within the recordset loop? What should these lines accomplish?

Comment: I think my problem is fields.update.  It looks like it updates all fields in all tables, rather than the one I want to update.  How would I tell Fields.update to update only the fields in the table I want.

Comment: No idea as I've never coded anything like this. I would have to recreate files and experiment and I am not interested in doing that work. That's why I suggested using another forum to provide files.

Comment: It isn’t `Fields.Update` that is the problem. From your description you have a very poorly designed document. As soon as the document is switched to Print Preview, or printed, all the fields will update.